# Draw on an image: PyQt and PyOpenGL

Tags: pyqt5, pyopengl

I'm trying to Draw line and shapes on an existing image using PyQt5 and PyOpenGL. I have done the following so far:

1. create an object of `QGraphicsView`
2. add an `QGraphicsScene()` object to it
3. add an `Pixmap` into my `scene`

I also created a class called `GLWidget` which inherits from `QGLWidget`.
The problem is that I can not display the `GLWidget` in the `scene`. I mean when I do `scene.addWidget(glWidget)` the functions (`initializeGL`,`paintGL`,...) are called but nothing shows on the screen.
I have to say that when I only display the `GLWidget` like this:

```
glWidget = GLWidget(self)
self.setCentralWidget(glWidget)
```

it works fine!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in PyQt5 examples in github here:
[PyQt5 OpenGL examples](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/opengl/)

The tricky part was in the `initializeGL` function which I had to do:

```
self.gl = self.context().versionFunctions()
self.gl.initializeOpenGLFunctions()
....
```

I hope it helps!